# Does Svelte store's auto-subscription work in non-component files?

Tags: subscription, svelte, svelte-store

Just a basic question: Is the $-syntax for stores applicable in non-component JavaScript files?

The [doc](https://svelte.dev/docs#4_Prefix_stores_with_$_to_access_their_values) says:

> Any time you have a reference to a store, you can access its value
> inside a component by prefixing it with the $ character.

However, this official [example](https://svelte.dev/examples#derived-stores) seems to use the $-syntax in a derived store which is not a component:

```
export const elapsed = derived(
    time,
    $time => Math.round(($time - start) / 1000)
);
```

Is this a special case for custom stores? Or is it possible because it gets imported into a component?

Comment: `$time` is just a function parameter name, no svelte magic happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, because only Svelte files will be compiled.

And you are right about the derived store. But this is only to make clear the callback receives the value and not the subscription. You can use other value names as well and you do not need to start with a $.

```
export const elapsed = derived(
    time,
    _time => Math.round((_time - start) / 1000)
);
```

Comment: The import of a JS file into a component does not mean that it gets compiled as well?

Comment: No. But of course you can use store.subscribe() or use get(store) here to get the currenty store value. Or pass the $store as a function argument to an imported js function. Imported from a js file.